# Simplify quotient of PSD matrix expressions

Tags: matrices, optimization, positive-semidefinite

I have the feeling that the following expression can be simplified, however i cannot find a way...

$\frac{|\mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{A} \mathbf{c}|^2}{\mathbf{c}^H \mathbf{A} \mathbf{c}}$
with

$\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}, \mathbf{A} \geq \mathbf{0}$ positive semidefinite

$\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$

This is part of an optimization problem over $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Yes. I double checked and it really looks like that.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what optimization problem you're trying to solve. Your question is totally unmotivated.